# Mysql query to sum decimal numbers

Tags: mysql, database, sum

I am trying to sum my decimal records e.g.

There is a column in my table named cash having values like 40.33, 30.00, 77.22. How can I create a query that sum up these records? I am trying hard using `SUM(cash)` and `ROUND(SUM(cash),2)` but no result.

```
SELECT cash FROM `enrolled
```

return rows.

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(cash),2)`
```

return 0 row.

Comment: Could you post your attempted query?  Also, what does "no result" mean?  Is it giving you a null value?  `SUM` should work, assuming you have non-null values to sum.

Comment: Can you post some sample contents of the cash column in your table?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

try this.

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(cash), 2)
FROM <tablename>
```

If you are getting no results, then there must be a null value, try this instead.

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(cash), 2)
FROM<tablename> a
WHERE cash IS NOT NULL
```

Tell me if there is anything else to help you with.

Comment: what is the column 'cash' data type?

Answer (score 3):

You may have NULL values in the table causing issues.  Try:

```
SELECT SUM(COALESCE(`cash`, 0.00))
  FROM MyTable
```

Should work just fine.  Demo: http://sqlize.com/0fZI6J0Oi5

Answer (score 0):

I would think

```
SELECT SUM(`cash`) FROM table_name
```

would do it

can you update your post to include the exact query you are using and

```
DESCRIBE table_name
```

Comment: what does DESCRIBE enrolled, display?